# Date Picker Control Using AjaxControlToolkit in a form (Comparing between 2 date picker )

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the normal **AjaxControlToolkit** & use 2 datepicker in my page.

**First date picker is taking the date which doesn't ex id from Today Date(today or any previous date). On the 2nd text box I can selected the date in between the date taken in the 1st date picker to Today Date.**

The Script code which i am using that works on the JQuery date picker. But it won't work in the normal Ajax date picker.

Here is the code As follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Date Picker</title>

<script type="text/C#" >

$(function () {
    $("#txtfrom").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $("#txtto").datepicker({
                minDate: date,
                maxDate: new Date()
            });
        },
        maxDate: 0
    });

}); 


</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
<b>From</b>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="ceLoanTakenDate" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"     PopupButtonID="txtfrom" TargetControlID="txtfrom">
    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
    &nbsp &nbsp
    <b>To</b>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="txtto"  TargetControlID="txtto">
    </cc1:CalendarExtender>


</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle client-side `DateSelectionChanged` event of the first extender and set up `startDate` property of the second extender:

```
<b>From</b>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ceLoanTakenDate" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" 
    PopupButtonID="txtfrom" TargetControlID="txtfrom" 
    OnClientDateSelectionChanged="ceLoanTakenDate_dateSelectionChanged">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<b>To</b>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="txtto"
    TargetControlID="txtto">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ceLoanTakenDate_dateSelectionChanged(sender, args) {
        $find("<%= CalendarExtender1.ClientID %>").set_startDate(sender.get_selectedDate());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The script code which I have used before in the head part, that code I have to use or not. @Yuriy Rozhovetskiy